# Interview questions for beginners and people experienced at Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am working on question paper for Beginnners and experienced people on Oracle,SQL/PLSQL.
Can anyone suggest me some links or give me ideas to judge a person on specified technology?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://www.plsqlchallenge.com/ - lots of questions there, ranging from very easy to quite advanced.
I don't know whether you're allowed to use them for a paper, though - you'd have to contact Steven Feuerstein (the site admin) for that.